# Cauchy's criterion for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Cauchy's criterion for series convergence is that for a  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}$ if

$$\limsup\sqrt[n]{a_n} < 1$$

then the series converges. If its $>1$ then it diverges and if its $1$ then this criterion doesnt give an answer

If we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

then how come that this criterion gives us an answer?

Because $\lim\sqrt[n]{a} = 1$ if $a>0$

But textbook says that the above series converges. So maybe the above limit is actually less than $1$? Or have i misinterpreted Cauchy's criterion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why is it that you mentioned that $\limsup\sqrt[n]a=1$ if $a>0$. That's not relevant here. What matters is that$$\limsup\sqrt[n]{\frac1{n^2}}=\limsup_n\frac1{\sqrt[n]n^2}=1.$$

But, yes, Cauchy's criterion does *not* give an answer in that case. That does *not* mean that there is no answer; it only means that the answer must be determined by some other method. In the case of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ you can use, for instance, the integral test. Or ot use the fact that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}):\frac1{n^2}\leqslant\frac1{n(n-1)}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 2):

In this case we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac1{n^2}\right)^\frac1n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac1{n^\frac1n}\right)^2=1$$

and the limit doesn't approach strictly from above, [Cauchy's root criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) is not conclusive and we need to refer to other methods to conclude for convergence, that is for example integral test or any proof for the [Basel problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8337/505767)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} =\frac {\pi^2} 6$$

Note also that the limit for $a>0$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(a\right)^\frac1n=1$$

is not relevant here indeed we are using that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(n\right)^\frac1n=\lim_{n\to \infty} e^{\frac{\ln n}n}=e^0=1$$

Comment: You fail to point out that the asker did not even use the criterion correctly.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks, I'll edit the answer!